# No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH environment variable. You must install a VM prior to running this program

Tags: java, ubuntu-20.04, path-variables

I know this has been asked several times but I can't seem to get rid of this error.
Setup:

- I have installed java on ubuntu 20.04 with sudo apt install default-jre
- echo **$JAVA_HOME** gives **/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/** which I see is correct.
- PATH variable is also set correctly. When I type java in shell it shows me available options.
- **ls** in the /usr/lib/jvm gives 
  default-java  java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-11-openjdk-amd64  openjdk-11

Error:
When I try to install lmadmin I get the following:
Preparing to install
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH
environment variable.  You must install a VM prior to
running this program.

Things I have tried so far:

- add the export path lines to .bashrc , .bash_profile , /etc/environment
- reinstalled the java package

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The jdk directorys and the jre directorys are different - similar errors found elsewhere indicate it is looking for something like .../jre../bin in path.  Sorry if a bit vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it has been too late but i encounter the same problem when installing the CPLEX progrom. I had found the solution here at [IBM support](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ds8870/7.3?topic=HW213_7.3.0/com.ibm.storage.ssic.help.doc/f2c_clijavaerror_2lfq3j.html). Simply pass the java path using the LAX_VM flag.

```
./cplex_studio128.linux-x86-64.bin LAX_VM /opt/ibm-Java-whatever/java/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to install S32 Design Studio from NXP.
Following the answer from @kkkaiqiang who used IBM solution I did

```
./S32DS_Power_Linux_v1.2_b170613.bin LAX_VM /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```